# Liouville measure and Bowen Margulis measure

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ergodic-theory

There are two natural measures on a Riemannian manifold such that the geodesic flow is measure preserving. One is Liouville measure and the other is Bowen-Margulis measure. Both of them are ergodic with respect to geodesic flow. The later is an analogy of Gibbs measure from discrete version where the maximal entropy(pressure) is attained.

I wonder whether there are some relation between these two measures. Would if be possible that they are the same measure? I would also appreciate for any recommendation of reading about these two measures.

Comment: They are not the same measure; in fact, section 2 of Katok's paper *Entropy and closed geodesics* (Dyn. Sys. & Ergod. Th., 1982) contains a conjectural list of all the instances of negatively curved Riemannian manifolds for which the Liouville and Bowen-Margulis measures happen to coincide. All of these are locally symmetric spaces. The Bowen-Margulis measure of a compact negatively curved Riemannian manifold is characterized as the *unique* maximum entropy measure for the geodesic flow.